# Why do I have wooden frames underground parallel to concrete foundation?

Tags: concrete, wood, foundation

I was digging up the ground outside to fix a gutter drain, and noticed there were pressure-treated wooden frames buried underground, parallel to the foundation (1st photo is the house; 2nd photo is the concrete retaining wall that juts out from the house, at the very bottom of the hill). Presumably these wooden frames were used to build the concrete foundation (the very bottom layer it seems). I thought these are normally removed once the concrete is poured? The house is built on a downward slope, but I doubt the wood pieces are holding anything uphill given their condition -- all rotted and spongy.

Any idea why I have these underground? Is there ever a good reason to leave a wooden frame underground? I think these may attract termites, so I was removing them, but I want to make sure I'm not removing something that should stay there. Thank you.
[image: concrete house foundation]

[image: Concrete retaining wall jutting out from the house]

Comment: Used scrape wood for building and figured better to leave than dump somewhere, too lazy to remove, forgot about them.

Comment: Where do you get "pressure treated" from?

Comment: You can kind of see it on the 2nd photo, but the wood has a bunch of small incisions (short lines, all in one direction). I was told that's what pressure treated wood looks like.

Answer (score 5):

Once upon a time lumber was cheap, and someone evidently decided that stripping the form boards from the footers wasn't economically worthwhile.